# Why i add And condition in IF function doesn't work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have following table,I used `{=MAX(IF(M21:M28=1,N21:N28))}` to get max value according to the same No 1 and it gives the right value `99915`.But if I want to add another condition, eg with same `name=hao` and same `No=1`. I should get `916`. 
This is the one i used here but give me `0`. Don't know why ?? Thanks

```
{=MAX(IF(AND(M21:M28=1,L21:L28="hao"),N21:N28))}

Name    No  Value
hao     1   10  
hao     1   11
rui     2   12 
rui     1   213
alvin   2   14
alvin   1   99915
hao     1   916
hao     3   9917
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "AND", you can just use another IF statement:

```
{=MAX(IF(M21:M28=1,IF(L21:L28="hao",N21:N28)))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . It works. Do you know the reaon why AND is not working ?

Comment: When you use "AND" in an array formula here, it evaluates all of the TRUE's and FALSE's only once and it evaluates them as a whole instead of row by row. If just one row returns a FALSE, "AND" will then return FALSE.  On the Ribbon, go to FORMULAS --> Evaluate Formula and step through the formula to see it in action.

Comment: Thank you again ,nice explaining !